# Cognos Workspace: Hide grouped row when condition applies

Tags: cognos

Cognos Workspace Advanced 10.2

I try to do a very simple thing but cant get it going.
I have a list table with order numbers and products. I need to hide every order containing banana. If I use a normal filter, it will hide just the banana line but not the grouped order line.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer on a forum...

```
Create a Query Data Item called "CountBanana" with this expression:

Case [Product]

when 'Banana' then 1

else 0

end

Create a Query Data Item called "TotalBanana" with this expression:

total([CountBanana] for [Order])

Now create a Summary Filter as [TotalBanana] = 0
```